# ConstraintViolationException thrown for Foreign Key

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I am getting a ConstraintViolationException when I try to saveOrUpdate using hibernate. When I insert a brand new object for a user, the save works perfectly but when I try to update it fails.

In the database table I have a unique not null primary key and a unique not null foreign key named userid

My pojo declaration is as follows;

```
@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name="userid")
private int userid;

@Column(name = "homephonenumber")
protected String homeContactNumber;

@Column(name = "mobilephonenumber")
protected String mobileContactNumber;

@Column(name = "photo")
private byte[] optionalImage;


@Column(name = "address")
private String address;
```

My insert statement looks as follows;

```
public boolean addCardForUser(String userid, Card card) {

    if(StringUtilities.stringEmptyOrNull(userid)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot add card for null or empty user id");
    }

    if(card == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot null card to the database for user " + userid);
    }

    SessionFactory sf = null;
    Session session = null;

    try{
        sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.saveOrUpdate(card);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Unable to add Card to the database for user " + userid );
    }finally{
        DatabaseUtilities.closeSessionFactory(sf);
        DatabaseUtilities.closeSession(session);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The exception I get says

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry '16' for key 'userid_UNIQUE'

And the database looks like this

[image]

What am I doing wrong, should the database entry not be updated?

Comment: So your method "addCardForUser" actually does update Cards too? Have you tried to log the primary key to check that you are actually updating one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For update, you should load the Card instance first, after some fields updated, then, invoke addCardForUser to update it, if the Card instance is not loaded via hibernate, hibernate will recogize it as a new record, if this card has the the userId with other card records in database, the unique constrain is violated!

Answer (score 0):

You should not put a unique constraint on your foreign key. The foreign key models a one-to-many relation ship. While your parent-objects may only have **one** user, the same user may be related to **many** different parent objects. Thus, there will not necessarily be only one row in your parent object table for one userId.

Comment: the foreign key in this instance actually represents a 1:1 model - one personal card can be owned by one user, one user can own one personal card

Comment: @Biscuit128 if you have a 1:1 model, then both of your tables can be merged

Comment: yeh i was reading that the other day, i wanted to try and avoid it though